# How to click on span element with python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Im trying to click on this for whole day with python selenium with no luck, tried several selectors, xpath..nothing seems to be work for me.
This is the element I try to click on:

```
<span style="vertical-align: middle;">No</span>
```

Here is my obviously non function code

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("No")
```

Comment: find_element_by_link_text ? is this span a link ?

Comment: No probably not, I'm just trying everything.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Search by link text can help you only if your `span` is a child of anchor tag, e.g. `<a><span style="vertical-align: middle;">No</span></a>`. As you're trying to click it, I believe it's really inside an anchor, but if not I'd suggest you to use `XPath` with predicate that returns `True` only if exact text content matched:

```
//span[text()="No"]
```

Note that `//span[contains(text(), "No")]` is quite unreliable solution as it will return `span` elements with text

- "November rain"
- "Yes. No."
- "I think Chuck Norris can help you"

etc...

If you get `NoSuchElementException` you might need to wait for element to appear in `DOM`:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='No']"))).click()
```

Comment: wow thanks man you are the king! After two days i tried everything, this was finally a solution!

Comment: find this solution after 2 hrs of effort. Thanks from my side as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing something in my project too for Spotify. This is the function I wrote to select genders which are in span html tags.

### Libraries Required

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import random
```

### Defining Variables

```py
gender_male = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Male']")))
gender_female = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Female']")))
non_binary = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Non-binary']")))
other = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Other']")))
pnts = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Prefer not to say']")))
```

### Using Random

```py
gender_guess = random.randint(1, 5)
if gender_guess == 1:
    gender_male.click()
elif gender_guess == 2:
    gender_female.click()
elif gender_guess == 3:
    non_binary.click()
elif gender_guess == 4:
    other.click()
elif gender_guess == 5:
    pnts.click()
```

### Full Code

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

gender_male = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Male']")))
gender_female = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Female']")))
non_binary = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Non-binary']")))
other = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Other']")))
pnts = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Prefer not to say']")))

gender_guess = random.randint(1, 5)
if gender_guess == 1:
    gender_male.click()
elif gender_guess == 2:
    gender_female.click()
elif gender_guess == 3:
    non_binary.click()
elif gender_guess == 4:
    other.click()
elif gender_guess == 5:
    pnts.click()
```

Hopefully this helped.